# RavenDB disk storage

Tags: ravendb

I have a requirement to keep the RavenDB database running when the disk for main database and index storage is full. I know I can configure provide a drive for storage with config option - Raven/IndexStoragePath

But I need to design for the corner case of when the this disk is full. What is the usual pattern used in this situation. One way is to halt all access while shutting the service down and updating the config file programatically and then start the service - but it is a bit risky.

I am aware of sharding and this question is not related to that , assume that sharding is enables and I have multiple shards and I want to increase storage for each shard by adding a new drive to each. Is there an elegant solution to this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

user544550,
In a disk full scenario, RavenDB will continue to operate, but will refuse to accept further writes.
Indexing will fail as well and eventually mark the indexes as permanently failing.

What is your actual scenario?
Note that in RavenDB, indexes tend to be significantly smaller than the actual data size, so the major cause for disk space utilization is actually the main database, not the indexes.

Comment: Sorry my question is directed for both main database and index storage. Just to clarify on the actual scenario -Say I have an appliance with N (which we would like to reduce due to licensing costs) instances of ravenDB virtual machine and no more ( due to Virtual Server Constraint). All the VM storage ( VHDs) are provisioned using a NAS , so I can scale storage quite a bit , as opposed to scaling the number of RavenDB instances to scale storage.

Comment: Edited version of my previous comment - Sorry my question is directed for both main database and index storage. Just to clarify on the actual scenario -Say I have an appliance with N (which we would like to reduce due to licensing costs) instances of ravenDB virtual machine and no more ( due to Virtual Server Constraint). All the VM storage ( VHDs) are provisioned using a NAS , so I can scale storage quite a bit easyly and cheaply , as opposed to scaling the number of RavenDB instances to scale storage. So at this point I would like to scale each of the RavenDb vertically.

Comment: Or in other words I know best practice to scale for load horizontally( sharding) but not for data vertically.